# Heatmap function in R dendrogram failure

Tags: r, heatmap, dendrogram

For the life of me I cannot understand why this method is failing, I would really appreciate an additional set of eyes here:

```
heatmap.2(TEST,trace="none",density="none",scale="row", 
     ColSideColors=c("red","blue")[data.test.factors],
     col=redgreen,labRow="", 
     hclustfun=function(x) hclust(x,method="complete"),
     distfun=function(x) as.dist((1 - cor(x))/2))
```

The error that I get is: 
row dendrogram ordering gave index of wrong length

If I don't include the distfun, everything works really well and is responsive to the hclust function. Any advice would be greatly appreicated.

Comment: How about making this example reproducible by providing a small example dataset, perhaps the first few rows of `TEST` using `dput(head(test))`?

Comment: a few rows won't do it, you may need (e.g.) `test0 <- TEST[1:10,1:10]; dput(test0)` and so forth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not reproducible yet ...

```
 TEST <- matrix(runif(100),nrow=10)
  heatmap.2(TEST, trace="none", density="none", 
            scale="row",
            labRow="",
            hclust=function(x) hclust(x,method="complete"),
            distfun=function(x) as.dist((1-cor(x))/2))
```

works for me.  I don't know what `redgreen` or `data.test.factors` are.

Have you tried `debug(heatmap.2)` or `options(error=recover)` (or `traceback()`, although it's unlikely to be useful on its own) to try to track down the precise location of the error?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.13.0 alpha (2011-03-18 r54865)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
...
other attached packages:
[1] gplots_2.8.0   caTools_1.12   bitops_1.0-4.1 gdata_2.8.2    gtools_2.6.2
```

Comment: Your example helped me to figure out my error. This method requires a square matrix and my initial matrix is not square. If I rerun the example of the code you've posted above, except use TEST[,1:9], then I reproduce the error that I was originally getting.  THANK YOU SOO MUCH!

Answer (score 3):

The standard call to `dist` computes the distance between the rows of the matrix provided, cor computes the correlation between columns of the provided matrix, so the above example to work, you need to transpose the matrix:

```
heatmap.2(TEST,trace="none",density="none",scale="row", 
     ColSideColors=c("red","blue")[data.test.factors],
     col=redgreen,labRow="", 
     hclustfun=function(x) hclust(x,method="complete"),
     distfun=function(x) as.dist((1 - cor(  t(x)  ))/2))
```

should work. If you use a square matrix, you'll get code that works, but it won't be calculating what you think it is.

Comment: just replacing x by t(x) works! This answer is the only one here with a real solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Ben Bolker's reply, your code seems to work if `TEST` is an n×n matrix and `data.test.factors` is a vector of n integers.  So for example starting with

```
 n1 <- 5
 n2 <- 5
 n3 <- 5
 TEST <- matrix(runif(n1*n2), nrow=n1)
 data.test.factors <- sample(n3)
```

then your code will work.  However if `n1` and `n2` are different then you will get the error `row dendrogram ordering gave index of wrong length`, while if they are the same but `n3` is different or `data.test.factors` has non-integers then you will get the error `'ColSideColors' must be a character vector of length ncol(x)`.